# Regarding database in react native android

Tags: react-native

I'm beginner in react native. I'm trying to build an app, that needs a database to store data. I'm completely blank about how to use a database in react native. I saw the example link and did the procedures. Need help to know how to access database from react native.

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are not building with native code (you have not access to the Android and iOS projects). You won't be able to use that plugin because it requires linking.

If you are using native code I would recommend you to use  Realm rather than SQL lite. Realm is a No-SQL javascript optimized database.

https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/

If you are not using native code (you created your project via create-react-native-app or through the Expo SDK Tools I would recommend you to use the expo.io API.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite.html

you can access or create. your database using:

```
Expo.SQLite.openDatabase(name, version, description, size)
```

then create a transaction using

```
db.transaction(callback, error, success)
```

and access your data using queries:

```
tx.executeSql(sqlStatement, arguments, success, error)
```